# Sorting iEnumerable with external iEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I've been trying to sort a iEnumerable using another iEnumerable as a point of reference.

My first iEnumerable "combinations" (the one which i'd like to sort) holds 67 items 
but the only important property of these items is InventSizeName.

My 2nd iEnumerable "sizes" holds 5 items and the items looks like this

Id
Name
SortOrder

What I would like to do is to sort combinations by using sizes.SortOrder where sizes.Name == combinations.InventSizeName.

The closest I've been is

```
        var sorted = combinations
        .Zip(sizes, (c, s) => new { com = c, siz = s })
        .OrderBy(v => v.siz.Order)
        .Select(v => v.com)
        .ToList();
```

This however doesn't compare the properties and set the correct order (obviously) and it gives me a List with only 5 entries.

I'm sorry that this question is badly written but I hope anyone of you guys could help me out here.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't compare the properties"? Which properties? Is "sizes" in the same order as "combinations" to start with? (If not, Zip isn't appropriate.) Can you provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Change `Zip` to `Join` when combining `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to join the two IEnumerables

```
var sorted = from c in combinations
             join s in sizes on c.Name equals s.InventSizeName
             orderby s.Order
             select c;
```